# The query contains references to items defined on a different data context?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

This throws an error saying The query contains references to items defined on a different data context. when i try to assign catName at the bottom.

```
this.CustomSettings = (
                                    from xx in DBContext.ProductCustomizationMasters
                                    where xx.ProductID == this._ProductID
                                    select new ProductCustomization()
                                    {
                                        ProductID = (int)xx.ProductID,
                                        CategoryID = (int)xx.CustomCategoryID,
                                        CustomID = xx.CustomID,
                                        CustomizationType = (CategoryType)xx.CustomType,
                                        DefaultFreeCount = (short)xx.DefaultFreeCount,
                                        IsDefaultLimit = (bool)xx.IsDefault,
                                        HasItems = ((xx.DefaultFreeCount == 0) ? (false) : (true)),
                                        CatName= (from yy in DBContext.CustomCategoryTbls where yy.CatID == xx.CustomCategoryID select yy.CatName).FirstOrDefault()
                                    }
                                    ).ToList();
```

i am makng datacontext like this

```
private libDBDataContext _DB = null;
public libDBDataContext DBContext { get { return (_DB == null) ? new libDBDataContext() : _DB; } set { _DB = value; } }
```

how it says it has two different datacontext, while things are being performed on the same datacontext.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you access your `DBContext` property you are creating a new `libDBDataContext` because you never assign it to `_DB`.

Try changing your code to this

```
private libDBDataContext _DB = null;
public libDBDataContext DBContext 
{ 
    get 
    {
        if (_DB == null)
        {
            _DB = new libDBDataContext();
        }
        return _DB; 
    }

    set { _DB = value; }
}
```

This is not thread safe, but it should help you get through your current issue.

EDIT

As @Servy pointed out there is a cleaner and thread safe implementation using `Lazy`.

```
private Lazy<libDBDataContext> _DB = new Lazy<libDBDataContext>(
    () => new libDBDataContext()
);

public libDBDataContext DBContext
{
    get { return _DB.Value; }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `Lazy<libDBDataContext>` for the backing field and it will make the implementation here both easier *and* thread safe.